# Why are some `file://` fetch calls allowed while others are 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked'?

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning javascript, so please bear with me.

I'm have two html pages, say page1.html and page2.html. There are two buttons on both pages, 'next' and 'previous'. The idea is to open the next or previous page in the sequence. I was opening the new page by setting `window.location.href` to the new `file://` url. Except, of course when it tries to access page**0** or page**3**, the browser shows file not found.

So I decided to try using `fetch` and opening the new page only if the `response.ok` is `true`. This is my function handling the `button.onclick`:

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
    else {
        alert("This is the last page.");
    }
});
```

It works as I expect when the page exists (it opens the page). But when it doesn't the console shows 1 warning and 1 error (and doesn't change the page at all, doesn't trigger the `alert` either):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///path/to/page3.html. (Reason: CORS request not http).
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

I searched around and found that non-http requests are blocked for security reasons (don't allow webpages to access local files on whim).

The thing that confuses me is that even when the file exists (page1 or page2) it's still a non-http request and yet it works. Why is it being blocked only when the file doesn't exist? And why am I getting a `NetworkError` alongside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` (in browsers, anyway) has [this to say](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-fetch) about `file:` URLs:

> For now, unfortunate as it is, file URLs are left as an exercise for the reader.
>
> When in doubt, return a network error.

In general, `fetch` doesn't succeed with a `file:` URL. Sadly, it appears that on Firefox, if the file being fetched exists, it succeeds, but if it doesn't exist, it throws a network error. (I guess that makes some sense, it's not like it could return an HTTP status code; it's not using HTTP.) On Chrome and Edge, it always fails, regardless of whether the file exists. In some browsers (like Chrome) the older `XMLHttpRequest` also doesn't (but on other browsers, like Firefox, it does).

The major difference between `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest` and setting the `href` of the page is that in the former case, code on Page A is able to read the content of Page B; but in the latter case, it can't — it can *go to* Page B, but it can't read Page B's content. Page A is replaced by Page B.

If `XMLHttpRequest` had been standardized in the security environment we now live in, I suspect it too would specifically disallow access to `file:` URLs.

---

Since Firefox treats the file not existing as a NetworkError, your code — for Firefox only — could be:

```
// With file: URLs, this ONLY works in Firefox
fetch(url)
.then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
})
.then(function() {
    window.location.href = url;
})
.catch(error => {
    alert("This is the last page.");
});
```

Or perhaps:

```
fetch(url)
.then(function(response) {
    return response.ok;
})
.catch(function() {
    return false;
})
.then(function(flag) {
    if (flag) {
        window.location.href = url;
    } else {
        alert("This is the last page.");
    }
});
```

You could use arrow functions there. I haven't because you didn't, but:

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.ok)
.catch(() => false)
.then(flag => {
    if (flag) {
        window.location.href = url;
    } else {
        alert("This is the last page.");
    }
});
```